# Numpy error when use fromiter with arcpy cursor

Tags: arrays, numpy, object, iterator, arcpy

Given the following iterable:

```
arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, ['SHAPE @', 'OID @'])
```

I am trying to get a numpy array using the fromiter method (I think it is faster):

```
dt  = [('G',arcpy.Geometry),('ID','<i4')]
arr = np.fromiter(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE @', 'OID @']),dtype=dt)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator
```

I have tried without luck also with a generator:

```
dt  = [('G',arcpy.Geometry),('ID','<i4')]
arr = np.fromiter(i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['SHAPE@','OID@'])),dtype=dt)
```

But I get the same error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator
```

And:

```
dt  = [('G','O'),('ID','<i4')]
arr = np.fromiter(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE @', 'OID @']),dtype=dt)
```

The only thing that works for me is to create the list and pass it to the array constructor.

I would like to know why I am getting this error and how I could fix it so that I can use fromiter

Comment: Don't try to do the impossible just because you hope it might be faster!  Look at `np.dtype(dt)`.  I bet there's a `object` dtype field.  If the array is object dtype, or object fields, it's not going to be "fast" by any method or iteration.  Such an array contains references to objects, same as a list.

Comment: @hpaulj Not faster?
I have been with this for a short time and I thought something would improve.

Comment: Before I expand my comments into an answer, you need to explain why you think `fromiter` will help.   A quick read of `SearchCursor` docs tells me fetching the geometry object is a time consuming task.  If so, the python/numpy iteration details won't make much of a difference.  `np.array` and `np.fromiter` are both compiled functions, so we can't explain exactly why something can or cannot be done.